# Any way to represent a random forest regressor model?

Tags: random-forest

currently doing some EDA into a random forest regressor that was built; there seems to be observations where the model prediction is off. what library can i use to visualise the representation of the random forest for me to understand better how the model splits for each node, etc.

the model is built in pyspark (pyspark.ml.RandomForestRegressor)

Comment: You coud use export_graphviz https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html